# System.Xml.dll and Delphi 6

Tags: .net, xml, delphi

I have spended two days searching the net for any tip about how to register System.XML.dll on my Delphi 6.

Somebody can lead me please to finaly import this on my Delphi? I want to use SignedXML.

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.XML.dll is a .net library. As such you cannot readily use it from a native development tool like Delphi. You could wrap it in a COM object. Or you could use the .net API to spin up the .net runtime. Or you could use Robert Giesecke's Unmanaged Exports to make the .net library consumable from your native code.

However, all of those options are rather involved. You will likely be better off finding a native library that meets your needs.

Comment: Look what I found with a quick google, I am correct if I think MSXML supports signed XML as well? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb608325(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: MSXML 5.0 isn't a free library. Require a MS Office license how I know.

Comment: @David I know that is a .Net library. But still can use .Net libraries in win32/64. Just need to register with RegAsm. In same time can export with same tool in tlb format. I already done that but unfortunately I don't got access to xml functions.

Comment: Having read your question, I had no idea that you knew that. You didn't talk about regasm. You didn't say what you had tried.